# how to parse watch command output to last 5 digits?

Tags: command-line, regex

From the command

```
watch -n1 "ifconfig eth0 | grep GiB"
```

I have given the output below.

Now i just want the last 5 digits before (GiB). I wrote an regex for it, and it seems to [work](http://www.rubular.com/r/fQHTdkCKLI)

```
(\d{1,4})(?!.*\d)\sGiB
```

The only problem is that i cannot use it with the command i showed above? I'm using ubuntu any help

[image]

Comment: why can't you use it with Grep (grep takes regexes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test will break if the server reboots or is very busy: `ifconfig` scales the units it uses depending on how much data has been transferred.  For example, a server I manage has this:

```
RX bytes:8697322454215 (7.9 TiB)  TX bytes:2151364718288 (1.9 TiB)
```

You might find it easier to watch the contents of `/proc/net/dev`, which is where `ifconfig` gets its data from.  Its contents look like

```
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
  eth0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
    lo: 1204278   13020    0    0    0     0          0         0  1204278   13020    0    0    0     0       0          0
 wlan0: 658883131  568453    0    0    0     0          0         0 56092206  420036    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

Comment: nice suggestion do you know how i can read the results /proc/net/dev in real time?

Comment: `watch -n1 "cat /proc/net/dev"`

Comment: Well, that *particular* regex test will break, but it's still *technically* possible to use regex to parse ifconfig output. Simply use `bytes:` as the anchor string, which should be constant.

Comment: @Flup but the problem remains the same i just want last 5 numbers not the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

try sed:

```
| sed 's/.*(\([0-9.]*\s\)GiB)\s.*/\1/'
```

Comment: can you please break up the regex for my explaination? e.g what does /\1/ means?

Comment: `\1` contains the number before `GiB`.

Comment: it output me the whole ifconfig thing not just the tx , rx bytes

Comment: there are many various versions, I use the latest `GNU`.